# In C++ what is the correct way to filter a vector of polymorphic derived classes?

Tags: c++

Here is an obviously simple example that compiles and runs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
    public:
    virtual double getArea() = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
    public:
    double getArea() {return 3.14;}
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
    public:
    double getArea() {return 42.0;}
};

int main() {

    vector<Shape*> shapes = {new Circle(), new Rectangle()};

    for (Shape* s : shapes) { cout << s->getArea() << endl;}

    return 0;
}
```

The result is that it will print every Shape in the vector.

What I do not know how to do is to filter the vector by derived class type.  For example, how to iterate over the vector and only do something for each Circle?

Thank You

Comment: One option is: `if (dynamic_cast<Circle*>(s)) cout << s->getArea() << endl;`

Comment: You could also have a `virtual` method defined in `Shape` and implanted to do nothing. `Circle` overrides this method and does something circle-specific.

Comment: @paddy thanks I am not sure why you answered as a comment instead of submitting an answer that could be accepted as correct

Comment: @user4581301 thanks I know that "works" but does not seem "correct"

Comment: @MaxWen Because it's only one of several possible approaches, and it will not work if RTTI is disabled. It was unclear whether you desired an answer that chooses an approach for you, or if you wanted to know what options are available.

Comment: For a one-off the `virtual` method is a bit of a waste; the added noise in the `Shape` interface may not be worth it. But if `Circle` does one thing and `Rectangle` is going to do something else, and `Square` something else again, `virtual` becomes much more useful than multiple tests and multiple execution paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you want to treat Circle's differently from other shapes, you should consider simply storing them separately from other shapes.

But sometimes you want to do the same things for all shapes most of the time, and something special for Circles some of the time.

In such a case, you'd do a dynamic down-cast to get from a pointer to `Shape` to pointer to `Circle`. If the `Shape` it points to isn't a circle, this will fail and yield a null pointer.

```cpp
class Circle : public Shape {
    public:
    double getArea() {return 3.14;}
    void circlesOnly() { std::cout << "Whee! I'm a circle!\n"; }
};


vector<Shape*> shapes = {new Circle(), new Rectangle()};

for (Shape *shape : shapes) {
    if (Circle *c = dynamic_cast<Circle *>(shape); c != nullptr)
        c->circlesOnly();
}
```

Comment: thanks and just to clarify dynamic_cast will return a (1) Circle* for a Circle or a (2) nullptr for any non-Circle?

Comment: That's correct. Oh, on an only slightly related noted: your `Shape` should also have a virtual dtor, like `virtual ~shape() = default;`

Comment: Isn't the `c != nullptr` redundant here?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Yeah.